# Getting the contents of a div using on-click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to implement a "button" of sorts using javascript. When a user clicks on the div, the div background should change colors, and there should be a pop up listing the device number. I am planning on using the number to redirect the client later. But right now, I can't get the clicking event to register. I had the event working correctly for a bit, but the value was always the final value of 'i'. My webpage also has JQuery in it.

Here's a JSFiddle and my relevant code.
http://jsfiddle.net/G3ADG/9/

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="device" id="device1" value="1">
    <div class="device-name" id="deviceName1">Name1</div>
</div>
<div class="device" id="device2" value="2">
    <div class="device-name" id="deviceName2">Name2</div>
</div>
<div class="device" id="device3" value="3">
    <div class="device-name" id="deviceName3">Name3</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    var devices = document.getElementsByClassName("device");
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        devices[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert(i);
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        })
    }
})();
```

Any help or input is appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed the ClassName call. The alert returned is still wrong though.

Comment: I don't believe `document.getElementsByClass` is valid JS, `getElementsByClassName` is though.

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByClassName("device")`

Comment: Whoops.. I was quickly trying to write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using jQuery - What you are trying can be done with this -

```
$('.device').on('click',function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
})
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/G3ADG/8/

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. How could I go about getting the value of the div that was clicked?

Comment: Man go get some sleep... :) +1

Comment: @jetbomber117 like this  `$(this).attr('value')` `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/G3ADG/13/

Answer (score 2):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3ADG/12/):

You just needed a closure to attach events

```
(function () {
    var devices = document.getElementsByClassName("device");
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            devices[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert(i);
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
            })
        })(i);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a `for` loop, just run `$('.device').each()`. I also added an alert to get each `div.device`'s value. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/G3ADG/10/

*Edit:* I did it with `bind` instead of an on click because that mirrored how he was doing it in plain JS. pXL's solution using `on` works just as well if you are not dynamically adding `div.device`.